# Issue of "Can't locate RPC/XML.pm in @INC (you may need to install the RPC::XML module)" while running ./evilgrade

Tags: xml

Getting Following error while running evilgrade by command : `./evilgrade`

Even after `cpan RPC::XML` the issue does not get resolved.

Or copying iscore file to to `etc/perl` did not help.

> Can't locate RPC/XML.pm in @INC (you may need to install the RPC::XML module) (@INC contains: /home/nalin/evilgrade /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28 /usr/share/perl/5.28 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /etc/perl/isrcore/shellz.pm line 36.
>   Compilation failed in require at ./evilgrade line 26.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./evilgrade line 26.

Answer (score 1):

Waqas' answer didn't work for me. I used instead `sudo apt install librpc-xml-perl` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to `/etc` with `cd /etc`.
2. Open hosts file in leafpad as (leafpad hosts)
3. Comment all ip6 or IPv6 related lines with `#`
4. Save file
5. Run `apt-get update`
6. Run `cpan RPC::XML`.